# How to set a text style to the Datatable?

Tags: flutter

I'm `passing data` to a `datatable` located in the `child widget` from `parent widget`. I need to set a `textstyle` to the text in whole `datatable` how can I do that?

**Child widget**

```
Container(
      child: widget.dataTable,
    )
```

**Parent widget**

```
DataTable(headingRowHeight: 0, columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text(' ')),
        DataColumn(label: Text(' ')),
      ], rows: [
        DataRow(
            cells: [DataCell(Text('John')), DataCell(Text('department1'))])
      ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **DataTable** widget, you can find properties called **dataTextStyle**.
Then you can use **TextStyle** as usual. Example:

```
DataTable(
  headingRowHeight: 0,
  headingTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize:14, ...),
  // for Heading Text Style
  dataTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, ...),
  // for Text Style inside Data Rows
  columns:[],
  rows:[],
),
```

you can check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) for more advance.

Comment: Is there any way to display text within the cells with different font styles?  For example, with HTML, you can markup the following sentence:

This is a <font color=red>true</font> story about a boy <font color=red style="text-decoration: line-through;">and a girl</font>.

Comment: @Steve3p0 Yes, that possible, create a new question I will help

Comment: do you by chance know how to do this with pluto_grid?